# Lag when viewing meshes in texture shading mode

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, performance

I've been working on a ps1-style model, very low poly, and was UV mapping some textures onto the mesh, but when I tried adding another texture, the viewport started lagging a ton.

I could still move the mesh around, but it was extremely slow and choppy, like 1-2 fps. I changed the viewport shading to solid, though, and it worked fine again. I had been working with the texture shading on the whole time, so I'm just curious why it started lagging.

I'm using a Lenovo laptop running Windows, 8gb ram, intel core i5-7200u CPU, and am using Blender 2.72

I'd really appreciate any form of help with this problem since this is probably the furthest I've gotten on a project.

The textures I'm using are 5184*3456 in resolution, maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Ps1 texture for world maps reached a maximum of 1024x1024 pixels and a lot of "sharpening filter applied, from photoshop".

If you're using such an old computer, the maximum texture will be 1280x1280 pixels for Ps1 styles. Your texture is causing the lag, yes. Upgrade to Blender 2.79. Most of texture mip issues have been solved there as well, if you don't want to go to 2.8.